# How to Send Json String to Controller in mvc4 and Deserialize json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the json object like below

```
Extension = {
"BookMarks":
[{"Name":"User1","Number":"101"},
{"Name":"User2","Number":"102"},
{"Name":"User3","Number":"103"}]}
```

I want to send this json string to my controller Action method and Deserialize the data

I want to pass the data to the partialview

```
 public ActionResult ExtensionsDialog(var data)
        {
            return PartialView(data); 
        }
```

Any help
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How are you passing the data to the action? Through ajax call?

Comment: i want to call through ajax call but i am confused how to use the ajax call

Comment: i want to place the json data into the view and open it in dialog box through ajax call

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your **View**:

```
function SendData(){
        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataToSend,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        });
}

$("#Updatebtn").click(function () {

             sendData(); 
});
```

In you **Model**:

```
public class YourModel
{
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

In your **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction()
        {
            var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;
            List<YourModel> model = new List<YourModel>();
            resolveRequest.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new StreamReader(resolveRequest.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            if (jsonString != null)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                model = (List<YourModel>)serializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<YourModel>);
            }
          //Your operations..
         }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where are the parameters for the action method to hold the data

Comment: the data are present in your `Request` Object, more over, the JSON you're sending is a List, so i guess your need to use `List<Extension> extension` as parameter if your need in parameter

Comment: Oops updated the answer, add a cast
`model  = (List<YourModel>)serializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<YourModel>)`

Comment: did you remove your `id` property ?

Comment: Yes i have removed Id Property from my model class

Comment: All of that manual reading of streams is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you have to read the input stream yourself. If you provide a model the binder should do it for you.

In your code behind:

```
    public class StatusInfo
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditStatus(StatusInfo info)
    {
        DoSomethingInteresting(info.ItemId, info.StatusId);
        return new EmptyResult();           
    }
```

And just use the jQuery ajax function like so:

```
function changeStatus(itemId, statusId) {
    var postData = { "ItemId": itemId, "StatusId": statusId };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Item/EditStatus",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("success updating status.");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error updating status.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data via an ajax call like this :

```
$.ajax({
  url         :    "@Url.Action("YourMethod", "YourController")",
  contentType :    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType    :    "json",
  type        :    "POST",
  data        :    JSON.stringify({Extension: data})
}).done(function (result) {
  //Check if it's OK
}).fail(function (result) {
  //Check if it is not OK
}).always(function() {
  //Some code executed whatever success or fail
})
```

`.done`, `.fail` and `.always` are not compulsory, it's just better in my opinion.

Then use it in your Controller as you've done.
It should be OK.

Comment: Thanks @ AlexB .. How to Deserialize the json data in controller action method

Comment: You can access to all fields of your `Extension` variable in your action method, like `Extension.Bookmarks`. Just try it.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer if it helped you, or let us know if you have other problems @user2815454

Comment: How would be the parameter in Controllers action method

Comment: In your `JSON.stringify`, you have to write the name the variable you want to pass in your controller, then `:` , then the name of the parameter in your controller method. Just look at my updated answer. For example, `JSON.stringify({Extension: data})` where Extension is the object you want to pass and `data` is the parameter in which you'll have your Extension values

Answer (score 0):

You can call the action and pass values like this. Just substitute your data with the data I have in the data section.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Schedule/Schedule/Create',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                datatype: JSON,
                data: {

                scheduleName: ScheduleName,
                description: Desc,
                Hol_Type: JSON.stringify(holidaytype),
                Start_Date: start_date,
                End_Date: end_date,
                Start_Time: StartTime,
                End_Time: EndTime,
                days: JSON.stringify(days),
                rec_type:1

            },
            success: function (data, status) {}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... how many paramters should we have in the Action method of the controller @ckv

Comment: You can have separate parameters or follow ravisolanki07 approach in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be like:

```
Extension = {"BookMarks":[{"Name":"User1","Number":"101"},{"Name":"User2","Number":"102"},{"Name":"User3","Number":"103"}]}
    $.ajax({
    url         :    "@Url.Action("ExtensionsDialog", "Controller")",
    contentType :    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType    :    "json",
    type        :    "POST",
    data        :      {"data" : Extension }
 });
```

Action method is same.

```
 public ActionResult ExtensionsDialog(var data)
    {
        return PartialView(data); 
    }
```