# how to send stringified Json from view to controller in MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send a stringified Json object on button click. I am trying as follows... On button click I am able to call the required Action method, but **it's passing `null` for the parameter**..

*MemberLogin.cshtml*

```
<input type="button" value="» Continue" id="btnLogin" onclick="PostData();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PostData() {
        var ObjLogInDto = new Object();
        ObjLogInDto.UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();
        ObjLogInDto.Password = $("#txtMemberPassword").val();
        ObjLogInDto.CaptchaText = $("#txtCaptcha").val();
        var StringifiedData = JSON.stringify(ObjLogInDto);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Member/MemberLogin/MemberLogin")',
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: StringifiedData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("ERROR:" + jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("SUCCESS:" + data.Message);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MemberLogin(string JsonStr)
    {
        var ObjMemberLoginDto =
            new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MemberLoginDto>(JsonStr);
    }
```

I am getting null for this `JsonStr`. 
Note:I have included Json2.js. `StringifiedData` in ajax call holds stringified data. as 
`{"UserName":"TEST13361","Password":"testpswd","CaptchaText":"gz8h4"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'contentType' property in your $.ajax(...) config is having problem.
Either remove the contentType so that it would be set to default or set a proper content type.
You can find more on content type [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Also as @Jai suggested, you need to wrap the "data" in ajax(...) setting to be a key-value pair with Key same as that of action method's parameter name for a proper modal-binding.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
data: StringifiedData,
```

to this:

```
data: {JsonStr: StringifiedData},
```

You need to pass an object containing `JsonStr` as the key name and `StringifiedData` as the value because at the backend code is expecting a parameter named `JsonStr` in the request but its not available there so it is `null`.

Comment: using data: {JsonStr: StringifiedData}, instead of data: StringifiedData, is not calling the actionmethod. Do I need some additional modification?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for MVC controller what you sent. You can use two ways:

**Send Named parameters to controller**

Like this *js*:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Content("~/Member/MemberLogin/MemberLogin")',
   type: "POST",
   data: { UserName : $("#txtUserName").val(), /*And more*/},
   //something else
});
```

Then in *controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MemberLogin(string UserName, string Password, string CaptchaText) {
    //Operations here
}
```

**Send a defined object to controller**

*Model*:

```
public class Test
{
   public string UserName;
   public string Password;
   public string CaptchaText;
}
```

*Controller*:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MemberLogin(Test test) {
    //Operations here based on test
}
```

And finally in *js*:

```
var _data = {
    UserName: $("#txtUserName").val(),
    Password: $("#txtMemberPassword").val(),
    CaptchaText: $("#txtCaptcha").val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Member/MemberLogin/MemberLogin")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: _data,
    //something else
});
```

**And If you persist in using stringified json**, tkae a look at How to Send Json String to Controller in mvc4 and Deserialize json[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292019/1743997)