# .net core DataTables - sending null parameter via ajax to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatable, pagination

I have the following `datatable` with server-side pagination:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example").dataTable({
            pageLength: 10,

            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' }
            ],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "url",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonObject",
                data: function (dtparams) {
                    return JSON.stringify(dtparams);
                },
                dataFilter: function (res) {
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(res);
                    return JSON.stringify(parsed.d);
                },
                error: function (x, y) {
                    console.log(x);
                },
                "filter": true,
                columns: [
                //columns
                ],
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

and my method on the server side:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredItems(string clientParameters)
{
    // Code
}
```

My problem is that the client parameters sent to the server are `null` but when I debug on the client side I can see the object like this:

[image]

I know there are some similar question about this, but I've tried some of those approaches like sending the object as Json.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: What is the purpose of that `ajax.dataFilter`? Why do you need it? What data do you want to extract using `parsed.d`?

Comment: For `dataType: "jsonObject"`, the valid types are `xml`,  `html`, `script`, `json`, `jsonp`, and `text`. I don't think `jsonObject` is valid - at least not according to the jQuery [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation.

Comment: the purpose of the ajax is to paginate via server side, the client params has the current page and the page size

Comment: I've tried with data type json and it's null also

Comment: Yes - I understand the purpose of the Ajax call, and how server-side pagination works for DataTables. My question is: _What is the purpose of that `ajax.dataFilter`? Why do you need it? What data do you want to extract using `parsed.d`?_ Doing that filtering will typically break DataTables' server-side pagination logic. You typically do not need it.

Comment: Maybe, couldn't get there yet since the server is not receiving correctly the parameters.

Comment: Remove it and re-test. And remove the `dataType: "jsonObject",`, also. jQuery is smart enough to auto-detect the type (which is `json` not `jsonObject`).

Comment: I've already tried that, I also added the [FromBody] and [FromForm] on the server side controller and still null

Comment: Another thought: You are using a `POST` so make sure you are looking in the request body in your .NET handler (don't look in query parameters). Sorry, I don't know .NET very well, so I can't really comment on how you do that. Maybe you are already doing that.

Comment: Looks like our comments overlapped. (The request body will be a JSON string, not form data.)

Comment: so in your controller action, the clientParameters comes though as empty ? is so when you debug that in the immediate window you can use ```?this.HttpContext.Request.Form.ToArray()``` also check whats being sent though ,worth checking this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291530/how-to-send-json-string-to-controller-in-mvc4-and-deserialize-json it should help you

Comment: What you sent in ajax is Json type, but what you receive in `GetFilteredItems` is string type, which does not match. Try converting your data to string.

Comment: but I do the stringify